# Custom splash-screen window freezes sometimes

Tags: python, pyqt5, splash-screen

I'm writing a splash screen (that's the secondary window) and I get a very weird behavior,
sometimes the splash screen freezes and doesn't respond at all (event to window closing)

I'm using *PyQt 5.9.2*.

***`main.py`***

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP = QApplication([])
    splash_loader = SplashScreen()
    splash_loader.start()
    sys.exit(APP.exec())
```

This main app creates an instance of splash screen and calls `.start()`.
The issue is that it only happens sometimes (like 1 in ~10 times).

***`splashScreen.py`***

```py
class SplashScreen(QWidget):
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._canceled = False
        self._connection_check_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.wait_for_connection, daemon=True)
        self._event_loop = QEventLoop()

    def start(self):
        self.show()
        self._connection_check_thread.start()
        self._event_loop.exec_()
        self.hide()

    def wait_for_connection(self):
        """ used to have connection check to some ip
            but in my case the problem happen even if the connection check 
            returned True right away
        """
        for _in range (5):
            pass
        self.abort_connecting()


    def abort_connecting(self):
        self._canceled = True
        self._event_loop.quit()

    def closeEvent(self, QCloseEvent):
        self.abort_connecting()
```

Comment: It might be more stable using Qt threads instead of Python threads.

Comment: Also, you should **never** use a block (like `time.sleep`) within the main loop of the GUI.

Comment: @musicamante time.sleep does not run in the main thread so I don't think it's the problem.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: @MauriceMeyer he Qt threads use the native threads of the OS in a similar way that makes them python so there is no difference in general unless the thread that handles the thread is executed in an event-loop

Comment: @eyllanesc ops, sorry, you're right, the indentation confused me.

Comment: @eyllanesc i have modified the code

Comment: @TomValershtein what is `run()`?

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry suppose to be exec(), changed it :)